# Django background-task throws an exception but executes correctly

Tags: python, django, background-task

I am trying to start Django background-task automatically when Django starts.

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.prod')    
    # Start background tasks
    if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN'):
        management.call_command('background_task')
```

Problem is that I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    management.call_command('background_task')
  File "/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 104, in call_command
    raise CommandError("Unknown command: %r" % command_name)
django.core.management.base.CommandError: Unknown command: 'background_task'
```

The strange thing is that after exception message I get "waiting for tasks" on console and everything works correctly. Tasks get executed without issues.
If I try to catch this exception then tasks wont work.
Any suggestions how can I avoid this error?

Comment: Just a guess: you are trying to run the management command before the management commands have been loaded.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to fix that? I'm new to Django

Comment: Usually you run management commands separately.

Comment: For example: run manage.py runserver and then run manage.py process_tasks in another terminal?

Comment: What is `background_task`? Is it from a library?

Comment: Yes: https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/